# ASP.net MVC ERROR after deploying on the hosting web site

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I get the assembly error
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Any idea what needs to be included.

Answer (score 1):

Did you make sure to copy the second web.config file that resides in the Views directory up to the host?

Also the following should be in the "main" web.config.

```
<assemblies>
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=1.0.0.0, 
     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
...
</assemblies>
```

Phil Haack explains how to [BIN deploy](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx) the MVC here if your host has notr installed.

Kindness,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

You will need to install the MVC redistribution files from [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/download/)

Answer (score 0):

Does the web hosting server has the MVC framework installed?  I am assuming you installed in on the development environment but not on your hosting server.  You need to install the framework also on the hosting server.

If the hosting server has the MV framework installed, check that the version installed on the development environment is the same as the hosting environment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your project to do bin deployment?

See this post by Phil Haack:
http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio in your project go to the reference folder find the "System.Web.Mvc", "System.Web.Routing", and "System.Web.Abstractions" and set the "Copy Local" property to TRUE. This will copy the files to the Bin directory of your application, when your app is built. Your webserver does not have these files installed, that is why you are getting this error.